# Multi-Threading issues

Tags: posix

Could anyone explain to me as to why my global array wordCount is containing nothing but garbage and 0's? This is just a small portion of the code that is creating issues for me, I've tried debugging but i'm working with ubuntu inside of a virtual machine I'm unfamiliar with their debugging tools.

```
int  wordCount[10];    //global int array
char buff[BUFFERSIZE]; //global char array



typedef struct myWorkers{
int startingPos;
int bounds;
int myId;
}myData,*PmyData;

void somefunction()
{
   //code
   //code
  for(i=0; i<THREADMAX;i++)
  {
    pDataArray[i]=(struct myWorkers *)malloc(sizeof(struct myWorkers));

    pDataArray[i]->startingPos=charDivided*i;

    pDataArray[i]->myId   =i;
    if(i!=(threadCount-1)){pDataArray[i]->bounds=charDivided;}
    else{pDataArray[i]->bounds=charDivided+charProcessed;}

    if(pthread_create(&ref,NULL,&myThreads,pDataArray[i]))
    {
        printf("error creating thread\n");
        return -1;
    }

   }
}


void *somefunctionname(void *void_ptr)
{

    PmyData pDataArray;
    pDataArray = (PmyData) void_ptr;
    int counter =0;
    int id = pDataArray->myId;
    int i  = pDataArray->startingPos;
    int j  = pDataArray->bounds;
     j     += i;

    for(i=i; i<j; i++)
    {
       if((buffer[i]==somedata......))
        ;
       else counter++;
    }
    wordCount[id] = counter;
    //  free(pDataArray);
    return;

 }
```

Comment: All Linux distributions (that I've encountered) that has gcc isnstalled will have gdb installed too. Learn gdb is my fist advice. You did not show the code for the actual threads "myThreads" so I would have to ask what kind of mutual exclusion or locking you implemented? What kind of manipulation does your thread perform on the data? Global data, in fact any data, should not be accessed by more than one thread without mutexes or semaphores.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think it would be helpful to see the definition of myThreads().

Comment: Thank you I just actually found the issue to my problem. I was calling (pthread_create(&ref,NULL,&myThreads,&pDataArray[i]) instead of (pthread_create(&ref,NULL,&myThreads,pDataArray[i])). Thank you though!